# Problem with importing local library in WebStorm: "Missed locally stored library for HTTP link"

Tags: html, css, angular

I am new at angular and frontend, so I am watching a learning course where man imported styles using this code:

```js
<link
    href="//demo.productionready.io/main.css"
    rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css"
  />
```

However, while trying to import this library I still get a warning of Missed locally stored library for HTTP link. WebStorm just doesn't wont to import it "//demo.productionready.io/main.css" even after pressing to import

I have tried to find solution, but found 0 articles about it.

Comment: If you want these styles to be applied on all pages of your app, just put that `<link` tag in your `src/index.html` files

Comment: that is what I actually done. However WebStorm still can't import theis lib

Comment: What do you mean WebStorm can't import it?  If it's a link in an HTML document that "importing" is done by the web browser when you view/run the app.  Your IDE shouldn't be doing any importing like that from a remote CSS file.  If this is a local file you will need to add it to `src/angular.json` to the `projects > [project name] > architect > build > options > styles` array which should already be linking to the main CSS/SCSS file in your project

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: can you share the index file please ?!

Comment: I have found the problem. Something just went wrong with my project